# Modifying default module source paths in python at the language level

Tags: python

1) I don't want to run git on my usr/local/lib

2) I would prefer to store this module within a /home/thrive/python_projects folder

3) I'm attempting to change where python sources the module from, when using the "import"  statement

I've found a few leads and I plan to post the answer here when I get it.

leads:

- http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

SO far the best suggestion is modifying the system path. However I believe that modifying the source with the language itself would be better for an open source project.

So how can I change this in Python?

Comment: In linux/unix you can add the path in you bashrc file, as
export PYTHONPATH=/home/Your_folder

Comment: imsc this seems like it might work .. could you add this as an answer and give an example file?

Answer (score 2):

In linux/unix add the path to the folder in the `.bashrc` file. E.g.,

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/usrName/usr/lib/python:/home/usrName/SomeOtherFolder/:"
```

will add two directories to the python path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you're looking to do this? If it's because you need to have different versions of a module on your machine, that's a problem [virtualenv](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) solves for you. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it definitely sounds like a job for virtualenv.

Comment: basically I'd prefer to have all the python related code im working on contained to a single file. So since I'm actually going to be modifying the module itself .. id like to locate it among all my other python code ... instead of the default install directory